# restart java process on heap dump

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I need to restart a java process if it produce any memory issues like 'GC overhead limit exceeded' or 'Java heap space'.
Is there some standard way of doing this like using some tool or options.
If not how can i put up a watchDog for doing this.
I noticed that my process is not going down when these issues happens.
And a restart brings it back to its foot again

Comment: The standard thing to do is to profile the memory usage so this doesn't happen.  Or you can have a script which repeatedly runs the program until it shuts down gracefully.

Comment: i have used a really dirty workaround, using process-builder, killing my own process knowing what was my PID.

Answer (score 2):

There are people here who will suggest better options, so this is just my 0.02$. What I did a while ago on some app, is have a SoftReference to an Object, and once in a while I would check if that Object is null. SoftReferences are being collected (usually, but not guaranteed) by GC right before you get really close to OutOfMemory, so that would somehow tell you that you are really close to failing.

Also, in this case you should be looking at the JVM option:

> -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=someValue

Where 'someValue' is the number of milliseconds a soft reference will remain for every free Mb of memory. The default is 1s/Mb, so if an object is only soft reachable it will last 1s if only 1Mb of heap space is free

It is probably not the best option, but just a hint may be?

Cheers, Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime#freeMemory()` will tell you how much memory is available within the VM - you could monitor that and raise an alarm when it reaches a threshold. Calling System.gc() at that point *may* free some more memory, but it isn't guarranteed and should be seen as a last resort.

You really need to combine this with understanding why you are running out of memoery and trying to do something to fix it.

Comment: I agree there are memory leaks in my programme. But then out there in production , until my next fix comes in , the show should go on.

Comment: If you are looking for a fix that doesn't include a code change, you could start the JVM with verbose garbage collection enabled, and then write a script to monitor its output. You should be able to recognise when you are getting close to a memory problem ( probably at the point where each garbage collection frees only a very small percentage of your heap, and the gc events are happening thick and fast ) and then take the necessary action - which really sounds like a restart of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**Tanuki Software Java Service Wrapper**](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html); it will handle `Automatic customizable response when something happens in your application or JVM.`

It has a [`filter` feature](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-filter-x-n.html) that will:

> Filters are a very powerful feature which makes it possible to add new behavior to existing applications without any coding. It works by monitoring the console output of a JVM for sequences of text. When they are found, any number of actions can then be taken.
>
> Examples are initiating a JVM restart whenever a specific error occurs. Some applications have known bugs where they stop working once getting into a certain state. This feature makes it possible to work around such problems immediately until they can be resolved in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Java application returns 0 upon graceful shutdown, a below shell script can serve the role of a watchdog.

```
#!/bin/bash

...

while true; do
  java ... MyClass && break
done
```

Comment: This wont work. My application will still go on crippled even with the memory exceptions